# Convert DateTimeOffset to string Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a search api which queries a given list of columns from a table or view using a given string.  As such, I'm converting each column to string.  This works well thus far, except for  datetime.  These columns are datetimeoffsets.  I'm trying to convert these columns to MM-dd-yyyy so that if they search for a value, it will ignore the time values.

The error I'm getting when executing the query is

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
.Where(f => f.Id.ToString().Contains("4") | f.CreatedDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy").Contains("4"))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.DateTimeOffset.ToString' failed.

So far I've got the following

```
    public static IQueryable<T> FieldsContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, List<string> fields, string searchValue)
    {
        Expression predicate = null;
        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");

        foreach (var next in fields.Select(field =>
                     GetFieldContainsExpression<T>(parameterExpression, field, searchValue)))
        {
            predicate = predicate == null ? next : Expression.Or(predicate, next);
        }
            
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(predicate, parameterExpression);

        return query.Where(lambda);
    }

    private static Expression GetFieldContainsExpression<T>(ParameterExpression parameterExpression, string field,
            string value)
    {
        var propertyType = typeof(T).GetProperty(field).PropertyType;
        Expression propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, field);

        var filterValue = Expression.Constant(value);
        var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] {typeof(string)});

        if (propertyType == typeof(DateTimeOffset))
        {
            MethodInfo? toString = typeof(DateTimeOffset).GetMethod("ToString", new[] { typeof(string) });
            MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, toString, Expression.Constant("MM-dd-yyyy"));
                
            return Expression.Call(call, method, filterValue);
        }

        return Expression.Call(propertyType != typeof(string) ? Expression.Call(propertyExpression, "ToString", Type.EmptyTypes) : propertyExpression, method, filterValue);
    }
```

Comment: The error means that Entity Framework can't translate you Linq query to a DB query (the Linq might be a valid Linq query). You have to make it 'simpler' to understand for EF.

Comment: How are you saving the datetimeoffsets in DB?

Comment: @PoulBak standard datetimeoffset format

Comment: *I'm converting each column to string* - oh no..

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown the part that throws the exception. But from what you shared, You're using reflection to generate lambda. This will not work with EF. EF has to translate each of your conditional expressions to something that is reognized by your target database management system.

As stated in the error, EF does not know how to convert `f.CreatedDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")` to something that is recognized by you dbms.

If you're trying to compare date parts only, you can either create 2 parameters, one for start of the day and one for the end of the day and check if your datetimeoffset column is between those 2 dates.

you can also investigate further to see if comparing date parts is supported by the EF provider. I've not tested this in EF core but it's probably supported when your dbms is SQL Server: `f.CreatedDate.Date == myDateParam.Date`.

Other workaround would be to fetch all data from database to memory (e.g. using `ToList()`) and perform your operartion on the retuned `IEnumerable` as opposed to `IQueryable`. This way reflection is also supported but it costs you performance degradations based on how big your data is before filtering.